# How to add a timecode on Netflix?

Tags: netflix

I was wondering if there was a way to add the timecode on Netflix on a computer. I need to watch a movie for college and it would be useful to have the timecode directly instead of pausing the movie every five minutes.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts. For further details follow the [tour] and checkout [ask].